# AngularJS | Como colocar meta tags diferentes en un sitio dinamico con NgRoute?

Tags: html, angularjs, ngroute

Estoy haciendo una pagina web con `AngularJS`, y utilice un controlador con `NgRoute`, y con `Ngview` pasa pagina por pagina como un sitio web dinámico, el problema es que quiero que cambie el titulo y los `metatags` por cada pagina que paso, y solo muestra el titulo y `meta tags` del `index`, osea de donde coloque en el controlador de `NgRoute`, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de cambiar eso?.
Mi codigo en js:

```
var app = angular.module('estudiantesDB',['ngRoute']);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){


  $scope.menuSuperior = 'parciales/alumnsCygnuspy.html';




}]);
```

Mi config.js que controla los links:

```
app.config( function($routeProvider){

  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'parciales/estudiantes.html',
    controller:'alumnosCtrl',

  })
  .when('/listalums2018py', {
    templateUrl: 'parciales/listalums.html',
    controller:'alumnosCtrl'
  })
  .when('/alumno/:codigo', {
    templateUrl: 'parciales/alumno.html',
    controller:'alumnoCtrl'
  })
  .when('/proyecto/:codigo', {
    templateUrl: 'parciales/proyecto.html',
    controller:'alumnoCtrl'

  })
  .otherwise({
   redirectTo: '/' 
});

});
```

El index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html ng-app="estudiantesDB" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <head>
        <title>Estudiantes CYGNUS</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="icon" href="images/icono.jpg"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>


         <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.cygnus.com.py/cursos/alumnos.html#/proyecto/{{alumno.codigo}}" />
         <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
         <meta property="og:title"         content="Proyecto hecho en el curso de CYGNUS" />
         <meta property="og:description"   content="Mira el gran proyecto hecho por un alumno" />
         <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.cygnus.com.py/cursos/images/Identidad02.png" />




        <!-- Incluir AngularJS -->
        <script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/config.js"></script>



        <!--Controladores de paginas -->
        <script src="js/alumnosCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/alumnoCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">

    </style>

        <!-- Wrapper -->
            <div id="wrapper"  >

                <header id="header" class="alt">
                        <a href="index.html" class="logo image"><img src="images/Identidad02.png"></a>



                        <nav>   
                            <!--<ul class="icons">
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-github"><span class="label">Github</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-dribbble"><span class="label">Dribbble</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-tumblr"><span class="label">Tumblr</span></a></li>
                            </ul> -->
                            <!--<a href="#menu" class="icon fa-twitter">Menu</a>-->
                            <a href="tel:+595984927729" target="_blank" class="iconoo alt fas fa-phone Blondie"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/cygnuspy/" target="_blank" class="iconoo alt fab fa-facebook-f"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a><a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=595984927729" target="_blank" class="iconoo alt fab fa-whatsapp"><span class="label">Whatsapp</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#menu" class="icon fa-bars" >Menu</a>


                        </nav>

                    </header>

                <!-- Menu -->
                    <nav id="menu">
                        <ul class="links">
                            <li><a href="http://www.cygnus.com.py/">Pagina Principal</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Cursos</a></li>
                            <!--<li><a href="alumnos.html">Estudiantes</a></li>-->
                            <li><a href="contactos.html">Contactanos</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </nav>

        <div class="container" >


        <!-- La pagina principal ira aquí -->

        <div ng-view class></div>


        </div><!-- /.container -->
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

La pagina que quiero que tenga el  diferente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="estudiantesDB" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<head>

</head>
<body>  
<div id="main">
    <section id="one">
    <div class="inner">
        <header class="major" style="font-weight: none; letter-spacing: none;">
            <h1>{{alumno.proyecto}}</h1>
            <p style="font-weight: none; letter-spacing: none;">Proyecto hecho por: {{alumno.alumno}}
        <img ng-src="img/{{ alumno.foto }}" class="image avatar img-circle">
            </p>
            <p>Proyecto hecho en: {{alumno.proyectohecho}}</p>
        </header>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</section>
 <section id="two" class="disenoProgram">
    <section>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="inner">

                    <h3>{{alumno.descrip}}</h3>


                <br>
                <h4>Comparte en Facebook:</h4>
                <ul class="actions fit small" >

                <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.cygnus.com.py/cursos/alumnos.html#/proyecto/1" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cygnus.com.py%2Fcursos%2Falumnos.html%23%2Fproyecto%2F{{alumno.codigo}}&amp;src=sdkpreparse"  class="button primary fit small fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"  target="_blank">Compartir <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>

            </ul>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


            </div>
        </div>
    </section>












</div>


<style>
            .avatar{
                width: 75px;
                height: 75px;
            }

            .puntero{
                cursor: pointer;
            }

    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: que has intentado? o en que estas fallando, agrega un poco de código para identificar tu problema.

Comment: puede replicar el error que tienes?